# What Event Handler should I use to change label

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying write a code so that once the value entered in the txtInput (textbox) is changed, the following labels lblName, lblPrice, lblSize would be should be cleared.

So far what I have isn't working as it automatically clears the label when I click in the textbox.

```
Private Sub txtbPrice_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtbModelPrice.Enter
        lblPrice.Text = ""
        lblName.Text = ""
        lblSize.Text = ""
    End Sub
```

Comment: What interaction do you want?

Comment: Use the Validating event instead.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you, that is what I was looking for. I am a complete beginner to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the `Validating` nor `Validated` event is appropriate. `Validating` is where you validate the current control, i.e. `txtbModelPrice` in this case. The `Validated` event is for code you only want executed when validation is successful. If you're not handling `Validating` then you shouldn't handle `Validated`. In your case, you want code executed when `txtbModelPrice` loses focus, so you should handle the `Leave` event. All three events will work but they are intended for different purposes so you should use the one intended to be used.